# Wordpress placeholder from "search here.." to "search"

Tags: wordpress, placeholder

I want to change wordpress placeholder from "search here..." to "search" in search area

I tried in search.php but nothing changed

Comment: Which theme are  you using?

Comment: I am using eCommerce Star theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way is jQuery
add this function in your theme functions.php

```
function search_placeholder_replace(){
?>
<script>
  (function($){
      $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input[type=search]").attr("placeholder","your new text");
        });
  })(jQuery);
  </script>
<?php

}
add_action('wp_head', 'search_placeholder_replace');
```